# Select target framework for ClickOnce app on client-side

Tags: .net, windows, clickonce

We are using a ClickOnce deployed WPF application designed to run on .Net Framework v3.5. The application does not work with Windows 8 or 10 and does not work if a newer version of .Net Framework is installed.

We receive the error message:

> This method explicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by
>   the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility
>   reasons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration
>   switch. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for
>   more information.

I do not have access to the source code or to edit the ClickOnce files on the web server.  I need a solution that can make the application work on our company's computers without requiring changes on the web server or in code.

Comment: You will only get this error if you run your program with .NET 4.0 (or the CLR 4.0). What happens if you run it under .NET 3.5 on Windows 10? Do you have .NET 3.5 installed? Do you have a framework override in your application manifest?

Comment: i am not sure, do you mean the application files in the c:\users\..\appdata\local\apps\2.0 ??

Comment: @Moh'edA-NasirDhagajuun, that sounds like you are using ClickOnce.  If so, you should add that to your question as it restricts your options heavily.

Comment: and what options do i have ?? if there are any !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link in the error message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191568(VS.100).aspx#Compatibility:%20Using%20the%20CAS%20Policy%20Legacy%20Option) gives you the answer:

> Compatibility: Using the CAS Policy Legacy Option
>
> The  configuration element lets you
>   specify that a process or library uses legacy CAS policy. When you
>   enable this element, the policy and evidence overloads will work as
>   they did in previous versions of the framework.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

So to re-enable the deprecated code, add the `<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>` element to `YourApp.exe.config`.

If you are using ClickOnce, you can [add the setting to `machine.config`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2518786/installation-of-system-center-operations-manager-r2-authoring-resource-kit-fails-on-.net-4.0-enabled-computers) instead.  Edits to `machine.config` are not reccomended, as they may have system-wide runtime or security consequences, and should not be attempted if another option is available, and never without testing.

Alternatively, if you wanted to run the entire application under .Net 3.5 (which is internally version `v2.0.50727` of the CLR with some extra libraries), you can instead specify the [`<supportedRuntime>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68(v=vs.110).aspx) in the same way.  This is not an option for apps deployed via ClickOnce.

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: as i said i do not have access to the application files in the server, but i can edit the installed files in my appdata folder, will this work ??

Comment: ClickOnce performs various integrity checks on the files in the `AppData` folder, and may or may not overwrite the changes you make.  If you can make the changes without them being overwritten, this will work.  If not, you may have to use the `machine.config` edit.

Comment: where can i find it ??

Comment: `machine.config`?  I linked to a KB article documenting the procedure.  See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2518786/installation-of-system-center-operations-manager-r2-authoring-resource-kit-fails-on-.net-4.0-enabled-computers

Comment: Thank you very much @Mitch, this was helpful, one last question, will it be help if I request from our application developer to add following line to the  run time section of the myapp.exe.config file ,<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>

Comment: That is one option, the other would be to have the app developer specify `<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>`.  If you find that this answer solves your problem, consider checking the green checkmark next to the answer. See the helpcenter for more: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)